# Why am I getting these exceptions?

Tags: java

I am getting these exceptions while trying to connect to a remote database, and I am not getting exact cause behind this? I am confused whether it's a permission issue or some network problem, or c3po connection pooling issue. Can you suggest something from where to start to solve these exceptions?

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor27.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2238)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2159)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor11.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:152)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1074)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1061)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1796)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:620)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'su01'@'10.15.9.137' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:935)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4101)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1300)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2337)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2177)
    ... 18 more
2015-09-07 16:47:31,990 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager-Helper Thread-#0] WARN [v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool]  - Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@dbe4e5 is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
2015-09-07 16:47:37,998 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager-Helper Thread-#0] WARN [v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool]  - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@17a3d13 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor27.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2238)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2159)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor11.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:152)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1074)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1061)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1796)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:620)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:935)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4101)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1300)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2337)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2177)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: `Access denied for user 'su01'@'10.15.9.137' `

Comment: `Access denied for user 'su01'@'10.15.9.137' (using password: YES)` What more explanation you want ?

Comment: i want more explanation because i am able to connect with same database using same credentials using sqlyog.....so why it is not connecting through code?

Comment: Can you provide some source code snippet please?

Comment: sorry bro i have just joined the company and starting to setup the project on my local.............so currently i have not much idea about project i can't post specific code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your database username/password is invalid.

```
Access denied for user 'su01'@'10.15.9.137' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: sorry but i crosscheck several times and i am able to connect to database using sqlyog with same credentials.

Comment: maybe the code is picking credentials from somewhere other than the place you've configured.

Comment: code is picking credentials from a configuration file.

Comment: Yeah Amila you are right code is taking credentials from an encrypted file..........i have solved the problem today

Answer (score 0):

I remember having issues like this one a while ago, are you sure you created the user correctly in you database ?

When I had this problem, the access was granted to 'user'@'localhost' only instead of 'user'@'%', so it was creating problems while trying to access the db from anything else than MySQL Workbench.

Comment: on checking access for user its showing like this in sqlyog:-GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'su01'@'%' IDENTiFIED BY PASSWORD '*.*'

Comment: And if you grant on 'yourdb'.* so it grants on all of the tables ?